# How to instance VertexWeightProximity before shape keys using geo nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry, shape-keys, vertex-weights

how can i instance VertexWeightProximity before shape keys using geo nodes? I want to animate the process (ShapeKeys ONLY) thru geo nodes because currently VertexWeightProximity modifier won't apply before shape keys, how can i turn around this using geo nodes?

[image]

- Edit : or if we can morph geometry using nodes to another shapekey we can achieve this

Comment: i think you are asking wrong. You should ask "how can i achieve such an effect" with geonodes. Because instead vertex weight proximity you could use the geometry proximity node...or did i miss something in your question? is this the effect you want to achieve? your gif?

Comment: You definitely didn't read the question title i guess , i want  wvp modifier to act before shapekeys so i can make parametric stuf , i think this is 100 percent possible to trick the software thru geo nodes ( the same thing possible to do with svrchok )

Comment: Should not be possible due to the fact that Geometry Nodes is a modifier also.

Comment: @Crantisz NOPE , shapekey think ( shape transformation ) can happen inside geo noder

Comment: It is not implemented, you can try to convert shape key to vector attribute using Python though.

Comment: @Crantisz and i know nothing about geometry nodes thats why i asked it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've asked about how to use it in geometry nodes. I don't know the way without using some python.

Let's suppose that I have a grid object with a shape key:

[image]

Foremost, we need to convert data from shape key to attribute so that Geometry Nodes has access to it. To store the data, I created an attribute, type - vector, domain - points:

[image]

Data is accessible for edit using Python. I wrote a script which converts shape key to vector attribute:

```
import bmesh
import bpy

me = bpy.context.object.data

# this line works only in edit mode, make sure that you're in edit mode.
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# put the name of attribute here:
ea = bm.verts.layers.float_vector['MyVector']

# put the name of shape key here:
sk = bm.verts.layers.shape['ShapeKeyName']

# We get coordinate of deformed vertex and subtract 
# the original coordinate to get the difference:
for v in bm.verts:
    v[ea]=v[sk]-v.co

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Once you've got an attribute, it is relatively easy to use it in the geometry nodes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you deserve accept as answer my friend i liked your answer ❤, but i want to keep it simple , i do have two objects i want to morph them together ( by keeping the topology) the same thing happens in shapekeys how can i implement that in geometry nodes ?